# How can I reduce the complexity for this case?

Tags: code-cleanup

How can I reduce the complexity of many ifs to check the same value, I'm trying to clean my code and I faced very high complexity on this case!!
P.S. its not if...else case its just many ifs throwing exceptions !

```
 void function(String text){
   if(text==null)
    throw new exception();
   if(text.isEmpty())
    throw new Exception();
   if(text=="test")
    throw new Exception();
   ..... }
```

Comment: "Code cleanup refers to the act of writing code so that it cleans up leftover data structures and other unwanted materials from memory and the filesystem. **It is not the same as refactoring code, which involves making the source code itself easier to understand, maintain, and modify.**" [codereview.se] is over that way <--

Comment: I guess this is Java. C# has String.IsNullOrEmpty(s). You could make a similar function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since each condition does the same thing you can have them in the same if statement:

```
if(test==null || text.isEmpty() || test="test" == 0)
{
    throw new Exception();
}
```

You cannot remove these cases since they are different. However, since I do not know the language you are using, you can potentially simplify the null and isempty check with :"isNullOrEmpty() in C#", additionally, you should use a string comparison for the test="test".

Best is to not throw an exception unless necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to throw exception if text is null or empty, you can just exit function. Throwing exceptions is costly. I would check these conditions separated by "OR" and exit function if true

Comment: yes you're right but I am writing test cases using jUnit soI have to test every line in my code .. what's your advice for this case?

Comment: do I have to ignore check null and empty ?

Comment: How exactly are you experiencing high complexity?

Comment: Depends on what you're testing, a null exception will probably be thrown by itself if you try to do something with a null string

Comment: Can you accept my answer by clicking appropriate option?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text)) 
{
    throw new Exception();
}
```

Or if you only want the code to execute when `text` is not null or empty, you can do this:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text)) 
{
    // do something
}
```